# Loss function in Keras does not match analogical function

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I compared the results, obtained via `model.evaluate(...)` and the ones via numpy. As you can see, they differ a lot. The kernel has just been restarted. Cannot find where the problem is.

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
import keras.backend as K

X = np.random.rand(10000)
Y = X + np.random.rand(10000) / 5

X_train, X_valid = X[:8000], X[8000:]
Y_train, Y_valid = Y[:8000], Y[8000:]

model = Sequential([
    Dense(1, input_shape=(1,), activation='linear'),
])
model.compile('adam', 'mae')
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=2000, validation_data=(X_valid, Y_valid))

print(model.evaluate(X_valid, Y_valid))
>>> 0.15643194556236267

preds = model.predict(X_valid)
np.abs(Y_valid - preds).mean()
>>> 0.34461398701699736
```

Versions: keras = '2.3.1', tensorflow = '2.1.0'.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the `model.predict` output shape is not same with `Y_valid`. If you get the transpose of the predictions it will give you almost same loss.

```
>>> Y_valid.shape                                                          
(2000,)
>>> preds.shape                                                            
(2000, 1)
>>> np.abs(Y_valid - np.transpose(preds)).mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky one, but actually simple to fix:

Your targets `Y_valid` have shape `(2000,)`, i.e. just an array of 2000 numbers. The network outputs however, have shape `(2000, 1)`. The expression `Y_valid - preds` then tries to subtract a shape `(2000, 1)` from a shape `(2000,)`... The two are not compatible, and need to be broadcast. Standard broadcasting rules will proceed as follows:

```
1. Align like  
(      2000,) 
(2000, 1)`

2. add extra dimension in front
(1,    2000,)  
(2000, 1)

3. broadcast to make compatible
(2000, 2000)
(2000, 2000)
```

...and so you are actually subtracting two arrays of size `(2000, 2000)` from each other. You are basically computing the difference between each prediction and *all* targets instead of just the corresponding one. Obviously, the mean of this will be much larger.

tl; dr: `model.evaluate` is correct. The manual computation is incorrect due to funny broadcasting. You can fix it by reshaping the predictions to `(2000,)` (or the targets to `(2000, 1)`:

```
preds = model.predict(X_valid)[:, 0]
np.abs(Y_valid - preds).mean()
```